# How to hide all buttons when one is toggled using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

How to hide all elements other than toggled button using jQuery ?

I am looping through comments and want the user to assign best comment using the following code while rest buttons become hidden and vice versa when clicking back on best answer to remove the "Best answer" status all buttons appears.

```
@foreach (var item in Model.PostComments)
{ 
   <a title="Assign best answer" id="@item.Id" href="#" class="btn-sm btn-default btn-best"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span></a>
}

<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
   $('a.btn-best').click(function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $(this).toggleClass("btn-success");
   $.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("Best", "Posts")',
    data: { id: this.id }
    });
   });
 });
</script>
```

Comment: you want to add hide all other button??

Comment: Can you elaborate your question more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hide using `toggle()` for hiding and showing the button elements

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
$('button').click(function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
$(this).toggleClass("btn-success");
//$.ajax({
//url: '@Url.Action("Best", "Posts")',
//data: { id: this.id }
//});
$('button').toggle();
$(this).toggle()
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="a">a</button>
<button id="b">b</button>
<button id="c">c</button>
<button id="d">d</button>
<button id="e">e</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use not() function for prevent to hide current click button

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('button').on('click',function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('button').not($(this)).hide();
    //you also can use toggle Class for hidden
    //$('button').not($(this)).toggleClass('btn-success');

    });
});
```